# Should I inform the hiring manager about my notice period?

Tags: interviewing, job-change, notice-period, italy

Last week I had a job interview and the hiring manager told me that they are urgently looking for a new web developer. He said he would interview other candidates and let me know within a week.

I'm still working for another company and when resigning I must give notice of 15 days. I informed the hiring manager about that but what I didn't know is that the notice period starts only on 1st or 16th day of month. This means that If I quit on 1st June I will start the new job from 16th June. If I quit on 16th June I'll start on 1st July.

I was interviewed just seven days ago. Do you think it is too early to contact the interviewer? We are now so close to the 1st June and I think that the new company is not considering this fact.

Comment: Please note that in Italy the length of the notice period mentioned when you sign the contract not necessarily is the length of the notice period you need to give when you leave the job since there are some automatic increments based on the level you are and the time you worked. So if the contract say 15 days, when you leave the job can be way more (up to six months)

Answer (score 5):

He should know that the notice period start on the 1st and 16th of the month since it is by law in Italy.
What you should inform him about is the *duration* of your notice period since it can change given your level, how many time you are working and so on, also if the minimum duration should be in your category contract, and you already done it.

There is also the option to negotiate a shortest notice period with the your actual employer, but keep in mind that this is a concession he is making to you (and he can refuse it) or, if you really want to leave, you can resign with immediate effect and in this case the consequences are all to check: he can accept this without problem or he can withhold your notice period pay or a mix of these.

That said, yes, it is too early to contact the interviewer since you just have the first interview and as the interviewer said, he is interviewing other candidates so, sorry to said brutally, you are not sure that you are the chosen one (or your question is not clear about this).

When and if the interviewer will contact you again for a second interview or, better, with an offer you can begin to negotiate the start date with the new employer and the notice period with the old employer.

Comment: He mentions in the post that he has told the hiring manager about the length of his notice period  _"when resigning I must give notice of 15 days. I informed the hiring manager about that"_

Comment: @KyleWardle quoting from my answer "_and you already done it_". I know he told him, but I need this introduction to explain the other options. (and for clarity).

Comment: My bad, must of missed that.